# How to use "tags" with rosdoc_lite to build documentation for entire Catkin Workspace

Tags: ros, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get Doxygen documentation generated for our internal project. Our project is a catkin workspace, with a lot of our own packages.

Right now, I have a script which will generate the documentation for each individual package, using rosdoc_lite. I am trying to understand how to expand this to use tags, and so each package properly cross-references each other.

My current attempt to do this (which isn't working correctly) is to run rosdoc_lite with the "-g" and "-o" flags to build the tag file, and output the code. Then I run rosdoc_lite a second time, with the "-t" switch that points to a yaml file that points to the output and generated tag files. My reasoning here is that the tag files need to first be generated, and then the second time all the cross-references can be generated.

However, this approach does not seem to work, and each package ends up not having the "Classes" tab on the top, and each package has the same set of namespaces that show up, which don't actually correspond to the local package.

Here's the excerpt from my script:

```
# First run through to generate tags for each package
for path in $PACKAGE_DIRS
do
  PACKAGE_NAME=`basename $path`
  echo "Package Name: $PACKAGE_NAME"
  echo "Path: $path"
  rosdoc_lite -g $OUTPUT_DIR/$PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_NAME.tag -o $OUTPUT_DIR/$PACKAGE_NAME $path
  echo "- docs_url: file://$OUTPUT_DIR/$PACKAGE_NAME/html" >> $TAG_YAML_FILE
  echo "  location: file://$OUTPUT_DIR/$PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_NAME.tag" >> $TAG_YAML_FILE
done

# Second run that should have cross references
for path in $PACKAGE_DIRS
do
  PACKAGE_NAME=`basename $path`
  echo "Package Name: $PACKAGE_NAME"
  echo "Path: $path"
  rosdoc_lite -t $TAG_YAML_FILE -o $OUTPUT_DIR/$PACKAGE_NAME $path
  echo "<li>$PACKAGE_NAME: <a href=\"$PACKAGE_NAME/html/index.html\">Code API</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"$PACKAGE_NAME/html/index-msg.html\">MSG API</a></li>" >> $INDEX_FILE
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141056/how-to-use-%22tags%22-with-rosdoc_lite-to-build-documentation-for-entire-catkin-workspace./) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jokla](https://answers.ros.org/users/13766/jokla/) on 2014-03-24**:
Hi, I have exactly the same problem...did you find a solution in the end?

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2014-06-23**:
Unfortunately, no I have not. I didn't spend much more time trying to figure out as there were more pressing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosdoc_lite` is not a general solution for all document generation, it is mainly a tool for automatically generating API docs for the ROS wiki, supporting Doxygen, Sphinx and Epydoc, all with limited customization.

Since you need to do some special things, why not use Doxygen directly? Then, you can customize your script as much as you like.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0